# Performance comparison in ways a SSIS package can be run

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis

I'm wondering if there is any difference in performance of a SSIS package if it runs using SQL Server job, vs running using DTEXECUI.EXE Utility or running in BIDS?

Also if the target database in on the server but package is running on a local machine, would it be using the memory on the server or the local machine?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Nazila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance should be the same between running it as a job, via DTEXEC or BIDS.

If the package is run on the SQL Server is uses SQL Servers's buffer pool as it queries the data, then SSIS will use it's own memory space to do work.

If the package is run on the client machine it'll use the SQL Server's buffer pool and memory on the client machine.

Running packages on other machines is usually slower, especially if there is a lot of data to move as the data has to be moved over the network.

Comment: Just to clarify, performance via dtexec (agent or commandline) and dtexecui would be the same. Running inside BIDS/SSDT will be much slower as it has the debug wrapper around it.

Comment: I agree with you billinkc, I can see the difference when run the package in BIDs (debugging mode) vs when run it using dtexec.